# Add value after date is end in list kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

hey I am working to create a list of type **INCOMING**, **OUTGOING** and **TIME** through **enum** class. My data class is populated through api call and filled according to that in the list. I want to modify to add TIME enum value whenever date ends the current one.

```
fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf(
        Conversation(ConversationType.INCOMING.value, Sender(1, "2021/10/12")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.INCOMING.value, Sender(2, "2021/10/12")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.OUTGOING.value, Sender(3, "2021/10/11")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.OUTGOING.value, Sender(4, "2021/10/11")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.OUTGOING.value, Sender(5, "2021/10/11")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.OUTGOING.value, Sender(6, "2021/10/09")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.INCOMING.value, Sender(7, "2021/10/09")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.INCOMING.value, Sender(8, "2021/10/09")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.INCOMING.value, Sender(9, "2021/10/09")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.OUTGOING.value, Sender(10, "2021/10/08")),
        Conversation(ConversationType.OUTGOING.value, Sender(11, "2021/10/07"))
    )
}
```

Enum Class

```
enum class ConversationType(val value: Int) {
    INCOMING(1),
    TIME(0),
    OUTGOING(2);
}

data class Conversation(
    val type: Int? = null,
    val sender: Sender
)

data class Sender(
    val id: Int? = null,
    val date: String? = null
)
```

I need output like this

```
Conversation(type=1, sender=Sender(id=1, date=2021/10/12))
Conversation(type=1, sender=Sender(id=2, date=2021/10/12))
Conversation(type=0, sender=Sender(id=null, date=2021/10/12))
Conversation(type=2, sender=Sender(id=3, date=2021/10/11))
Conversation(type=2, sender=Sender(id=4, date=2021/10/11))
Conversation(type=2, sender=Sender(id=5, date=2021/10/11))
Conversation(type=0, sender=Sender(id=null, date=2021/10/11))
Conversation(type=2, sender=Sender(id=6, date=2021/10/09))
Conversation(type=1, sender=Sender(id=7, date=2021/10/09))
Conversation(type=1, sender=Sender(id=8, date=2021/10/09))
Conversation(type=1, sender=Sender(id=9, date=2021/10/09))
Conversation(type=0, sender=Sender(id=null, date=2021/10/09))
Conversation(type=2, sender=Sender(id=10, date=2021/10/08))
Conversation(type=0, sender=Sender(id=null, date=2021/10/08))
Conversation(type=2, sender=Sender(id=11, date=2021/10/07))
Conversation(type=0, sender=Sender(id=null, date=2021/10/07))
```

Comment: I think your base design would be greatly simplified through the use of sealed classes/interfaces. I recommend reading up on them. I would make Conservation a sealed class with subclasses OutgoingConservation, IncomingConversation, and TimeConservation, and eliminate the Type variable. I'd also eliminate the Sender class and put its properties directly in Conversation, and make the date non-nullable.

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 I am using recyclerview on based that I am changing view type holder. So in this case sealed class/interface not work i guess.. Thanks for always helping me.

Comment: It can work in RecyclerView. With a sealed class you use `is` checks instead of checking the enum type.

Comment: can you please give me example. How to work that and how can i add value in TIME in list? @Tenfour04

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your app? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry for wrong explanations. can you see the example please.

Comment: Also, Care more about inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to add items to the list while you're iterating it, you need to iterate the indices so you can insert items as you go. Since the list is growing as you go, you need to use a while loop instead of a for loop with the original indices.

```
var previousDate: String? = null
var i = 0
while (i < list.size) {
    val newDate = list[i].date
    if (newDate != previousDate && previousDate != null) {
        list.add(i++, Conversation(ConversationType.TIME.value, Sender(null, previousDate)))
    }
    previousDate = newDate
    i++
}
```

---

To explain my suggestion about simplifying using sealed interfaces, here is how I would redesign. I would replace your above classes with:

```
sealed interface Conversation {
    val date: String
}

sealed interface ConversationMessage: Conversation {
    val senderId: Int
}

data class IncomingConversation(
    override val date: String,
    override val senderId: Int
): ConversationMessage

data class OutgoingConversation(
    override val date: String,
    override val senderId: Int
): ConversationMessage

data class TimeStampConversation(override val date: String): Conversation
```

Then you don't have to worry about anything being null, you don't have to unpack enum values, and all the constructors are much easier to use. You can use `when` statements with `is` checks to determine which view holder to work with in your RecyclerView.

Comment: great solution. It's not working for last element.

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question. Add one more statement after the loop to add the last item. `if (previousDate != null) list.add(Conversation(ConversationType.TIME.value, Sender(null, previousDate)))`

Comment: list.add(i++ , ... ?    list.add(i+1

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry for that. I Updated my question what i want to do. Can you please suggest me how to do inside `groupByDate` function in for loop. Thanks

Comment: @vivekmodi please edit your question back to the original and open a new one. The point of SO is to create a resource so each question will be useful to many other future readers. By changing your question completely after several people answered, you causing our existing answers that we spent time on to be useless to future readers because they no longer match your question.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i updated to orignal

Answer (score 3):

As I understand what you want, You need something like this:

```
var previousDate: String? = null
var i = -1
while (i < list.size) {
    i++
    val currentDate = list[i].date
    previousDate?.let {
        if (currentDate != previousDate) {
            list.add(i + 1, Conversation(ConversationType.TIME.value, Sender(null, it)))
        }
    }
    previousDate = currentDate
}
```

Comment: i want to programmatically not to enter date by manually.

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look again. Sorry and Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Other people already provided solutions based on manual iteration over indexes. Alternative that could be easier to read is to use mutable iterators. The resulting code is almost the same as your original attempt:

```kotlin
val iter = list.listIterator()
var previousDate = iter.next().sender?.date
iter.forEach { conversation ->
    val date = conversation.sender?.date
    if (date != previousDate) {
        iter.add(Conversation(...))
        previousDate = date
    }
}
```

With mutable iterators we can just add an item at the point where it is needed during iterating. We don't need to manage indexes manually.

This solution will throw an exception if the list is empty, so we should probably add a check for that case. You should also consider the case where `sender` or `date` is `null`. All solutions provided so far will behave odd in this case and you didn't specify what is your expected behavior.

Comment: Hey @broot thanks for reply. I update my question. Please have a look again. Thanks

Comment: You just changed 75% of your question. You can't expect people to re-read everything or make diffs to keep up and adapt to your changing needs. Now, this is really a different question.

Comment: sorry for that I though previous will work well. But it's not work well.  That's why I change the question. Sorry once again